# Smarty shows whitepage most time

Tags: smarty

Hi I have an application which is developed used Smarty 2.6.26 template engine.

The application was working fine till last week.  Now I am getting a strange scene.  Sometimes or frequently my sites displays whitepage instead of my website contents.  Cleaning the templates_c directory fixes the issue.  But this happens on a continuous bases.  I have not enabled the smarty caching in my application.

Any help highly appreciated.

### Things I have already tried

```
$smarty->compile_check = false; ( changed to false from true )
```

My Current Smarty settings

```
define('SMARTY_DIR', 'Smarty/libs/');

require_once(SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = false;

$smarty->debugging = false;

$smarty->template_dir = 'view';

$smarty->compile_dir =  'templates_c';
```

Comment: have you tried the {debug} function?

Comment: no, I will try that.  Thanks alot for the quick reply.

Comment: Have a look at PHP's error_log. There should be a message, at the time the error rises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if it's compile caching by setting [`force_compile`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.force.compile.tpl).

```
$smarty->force_compile = true;
```

**This should only be used for debugging.**  I have the same problem as you when I am working in my development environment when I try to refresh the browser to see the changes and the changed file has not finished copying to the test server.